# player object undefined only in update()ƒ

Tags: javascript, scope, phaser-framework

not exactly sure what to call whats going on. I need to create a definition for the clients main player physics body and i can't read it or any of its properties, no matter where or how i call it, from update(). Also if this is a bit hard to understand Im a young and new JS programmer so bare with me. Im willing to change the construction of my scenes if i need to if anyone recommends something easier.

```
    class MainScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
      super({ key: 'MainScene' })
    }

    preload() {
        this.load.image('grass','./assets/map.png',);
        this.load.spritesheet('graf', './assets/wang.png', { frameWidth: 200, frameHeight: 170})
      }
    
    create() {
      this.add.image(100,400,'grass');
      this.playerMap = {};
      Client.askNewPlayer();
      window.myScene = this;
      this.body  = this.matter.bodies.circle(
          1,
          1,
          10,
          {
              isSensor: true
          }
          );
    }
    addNewPlayer(id, x, y) {
        if(id == clientID){
            this.playerMap[id] = this.matter.add.sprite(x, y, 'graf','', {'shape' : this.body['player-20-00']}).setScale(.5);
            this.player = this.playerMap[id];
            this.cameras.main.centerOn(this.player.x, this.player.y)
        }
        else{
        this.playerMap[id] = this.add.sprite(x,y,'graf').setScale(.5);
        }
    }
    removePlayer(id){
        this.playerMap[id].destroy();
    delete this.playerMap[id];
    }
    movePlayer(id, x, y) {       
        // var player = this.playerMap[id];
        // var distance = Phaser.Math.Distance.Between(player.x,player.y,x,y);
        // var duration = distance*10;
        // var tween = this.add.tween(player);
        // tween.to({x:x,y:y}, duration);
        // tween.start();
        
    }
  
    update(){
       //haven't been able to access any variables Ive called from here
       this.cameras.main.centerOn(this.player.x, this.player.y)//causes error "can't read properties of undefined"
//replacing this.player.y or y with playerMap[a].x or y doesn't work either even though its accessible from everywhere else and === (equivalent) 
    }
}
```

here is the client object, I'm pretty sure this doesn't affect my problem

```
var Client = {};
var clientID;
Client.socket = io.connect();
Client.askNewPlayer = function(){
    Client.socket.emit('newplayer');
}
Client.socket.on('newplayer',function(data){
    window.myScene.addNewPlayer(data.id,data.x,data.y);
});

Client.socket.on('allplayers',function(data){
    console.log(data);
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        window.myScene.addNewPlayer(data[i].id,data[i].x,data[i].y);
    }
});

Client.socket.on('remove',function(id){
    window.myScene.removePlayer(id);
});
Client.socket.on('move',function(data){
    window.myScene.movePlayer(data.id,data.x,data.y);
});
Client.socket.on('id',function(id){
    clientID = id;
})
```

Comment: how DO you call it? how do you try to access whatever it is you can't access - sometimes `this.update = this.update.bind(this)` in the constructor helps when you want to ensure `this` is correct

Comment: Which variables can't you access? how are you trying to access them? please update your question showing the wrong / not working code( with other wordes, more details to the `update` function and share the definition of the `Client` Object).

Comment: The problem happens when in update I use this.player.x or this.playerMap[a].x, where a is any populated index. Using .y doesn't work either it can't read the attribute or the object, it comes back as undefined. As in playerMap and player are undefined. On mobile currently and I can't find a way to edit my question, I'll do it once I get in my computer

Comment: @Bravo I put ```this.update = this.update.bind(this)``` on the next line after my super and it didn't work same error

Comment: sure, but you still haven't shown how `update` is called - so, you're still doing it wrong - so the error isn't with `this.cameras.main.centerOn` but with `this.player.x` ... so, perhaps `this.player` is undefined - which it is until `addNewPlayer` is called with `id == clientID`

Comment: @Bravo `update` is a function/structure of the phaser framework it is called about 60 times per second _(aka the game-loop)_

Comment: @nojared I posted a answer I hope this solves your problem

Comment: great ... that doesn't show HOW it's called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, that the `update` function is called, before a `player` is added *( aka before the `this.player` is set)*.

Since the `update` function will fire more or less right after the `create` function, the property `player` of the scene is not set yet. So `this.player` is `undefined`, which is the cause for the the error.

**The solution** is to check, if the `this.player` property is set before accessing it, in the `update` function.

As soon as the `this.player` property is set, the other commands in the `if` - clause are called.

```
update(){
    if(this.player){
      this.cameras.main.centerOn(this.player.x, this.player.y);
      // ...
    }
}
```

or like this, it is a bit better to read *(following the **"Return Early Pattern"** )*:

```
update(){
    if(!this.player){
        return ;
    }
    this.cameras.main.centerOn(this.player.x, this.player.y);
    // ...
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out! it makes sense and it seems so small and stupid. The event that calls for newPlayer happens after the whole scene is initialized because socket sends messages which would call it after the scene is prepared, which makes also calls to the importance of the create function(that i didn't really grasp). Your advice will probably help me out a lot as I keep working on this project.